# android ExifInterface platform 1.5, 1.6

Tags: android, image, geolocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android image exif reader 3rd party api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536194/android-image-exif-reader-3rd-party-api)

ExifInterface is available from platform 1.7 how to read exif tags from image on platform 1.5, 1.6 ?

Comment: This is a duplicate question with 2536194.  Can they be combined?