# How to determine orientation of picture without ExifInterface?

Tags: android, orientation, exif

I load an image into a `bitmap` and need to know the orientation of the taken picture (from camera) to show it correctly. The way to use the following code is working nice (since API Level 5), but what to do if `android:minSdkVersion="4"`? Is there another way?

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(SourceFileName);     //Since API Level 5
String exifOrientation = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
```

Comment: Would it be a possibility to compare the height vs the width of the image?

Comment: @Roflcoptr, it's not so simply :) I need to know in which mode the picture was taked

Comment: can any one help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379130/how-to-set-camera-image-orientation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy implement your own [exif reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536194/android-image-exif-reader-3rd-party-api/2571105#2571105)

Then

```
Metadata metadata = JpegMetadataReader.readMetadata(new File(imagePath));
Directory jpegDirectory = metadata.getDirectory(JpegDirectory.class);
 int height = jpg.GetImageHeight();
 int width = jpg.GetImageWidth();
```

Comment: i  need help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379130/how-to-set-camera-image-orientation

Answer (score 7):

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

ExifInterface exifReader = new ExifInterface(filePath);

int orientation = exifReader.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, -1);

if (orientation ==ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL) {

// Do nothing. The original image is fine.
} else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {

       matrix.postRotate(90);

} else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {

       matrix.postRotate(180);

} else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {

       matrix.postRotate(270);

}
```