# How to get the orientation of a Bitmap in Android

Tags: android

I want to get the orientation of bitmap images. I tried the following-

```
Bitmap test = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri);
int w = test.getWidth();
int h = test.getHeight();
```

However it returns w=2592 & h=1944 *(for all images captured by the camera)* irrespective of whether it was taken in landscape or portrait mode. Is this the correct approach or is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) if you are using API level 5 or higher. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5309863/622645).