# Using Android Camera API, snapped photo's orientation is always Undefined

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, orientation, exif

I use the camera api and the photo taken is always rotated by 90 degree, and i would like to rotate it.

So first of all i would like to know the picture's orientation and this point im stuck.
I always getting UNDEFINDED orientation in both ways.

Here is the code:

```
    @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {


            //Bitmap Options for lowering quality the bitmap to save memory
            Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 4;
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

            //Make the bitmap
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);

            //Making the path, the root will be fine for tests
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

            //output stream
            OutputStream outputStream = null;
            //Making the file as a jpg
            File file = new File(path, "tmp_pic" + ".jpg"); // the File to save to
            try {

                //Writing the file
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close(); // do not forget to close the stream


                //Getting the orientation in both possible ways
                int ori = getOrientationFromExif(file.getPath());
                int ori2 = getOrientationFromUri(Uri.fromFile(file));
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (bitmap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: Cant make photo.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                PhotoTapView.photoViews.get(index).setPhotoImage(bitmap);
                finish();
            }
            cameraObject.release();
        }
```

The functions for orientation:

```
    //Getting orientation from file URI
    private int getOrientationFromUri(Uri imageUri) {
    String[] orientationColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION };
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(imageUri, orientationColumn, null, null, null);
    int orientation = -1;
    if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
        orientation = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(orientationColumn[0]));
    }
    Log.i("Orientation from Uri", orientation + "");
    return orientation;
}

    //Getting orientation from ExifInterface  
    private static int getOrientationFromExif(String imagePath) {
    int orientation = -1;
    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
        int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        Log.i("Orientation from Exif: ", exifOrientation + "");
        switch (exifOrientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                orientation = 270;
                Log.i("Orientation from Exif", "270");
            break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                orientation = 180;
                Log.i("Orientation from Exif", "180");
            break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                Log.i("Orientation from Exif", "90");
                orientation = 90;
            break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                orientation = 0;
                Log.i("Orientation from Exif", "0 - Normal");
            break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED:
                orientation = -1;
                Log.e("Orientation from Exif", "UNDEFINED");
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {}
    return orientation;
}
```

Log output:

```
01-14 19:46:09.468: E/Orientation from Exif(12411): UNDEFINED
01-14 19:46:09.468: I/Orientation from Uri(12411): -1
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: It appears that on more powerful (recent) Android hardware, the EXIF orientation is not specified because the camera app rotates the pixels before encoding the JPEG. On slower hardware (the old days), the image would be written in the default orientation and the actual orientation would be saved in the EXIF info.

Comment: So is there a way to actually do this ?

Comment: It looks like you can only tell if the image was taken in portrait or landscape based on the width and height. True orientation doesn't seem to be available.

Comment: @BitBank add this information as an answer if you want and i will accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have been decoding/observing Android JPEG images since early 2011 because I published an image viewing application. In the 'early' days, the images were encoded in the sensor's native orientation and the actual orientation of the device was written into the EXIF metadata. Starting about 2 years ago, I noticed that the orientation was no longer being written into the EXIF data and instead, the camera app was rotating the image pixels before encoding the JPEG files. My guess is that this occurred because some photo viewers (* cough * Windows * cough *) ignore the EXIF orientation when displaying JPEG files and instead of waiting for Microsoft to fix it and blaming Android for doing something wrong, they decided to make use of the faster CPU/memory and just rotate the image.

The result is that without knowing the EXIF orientation, one can only determine that a photo was captured in landscape or portrait orientation. This bit of info is only an assumption because the majority of camera sensors are wider than they are tall.

Comment: My godness I was looking for this kind of answer for 2 days. Because your answer I found an updated answer that really works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26141254/1332549

Comment: The best approach to deal with orientation photos is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26141254/1332549).

Comment: FYI - on the Galaxy S6, Samsung writes the EXIF orientation tag, so it's not universally lost.

Comment: Are you saying that there is no way to tell if the photo was taken in landscape or portrait if there is no exif data? I have great problems with Samsung Galaxy 5 devices, please take a look at my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090603/gallery-images-taken-on-samsung-androids-always-in-landscape-even-if-taken-in-po

Answer (score 1):

In this code

```
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outputStream);  // Add this line
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close(); // do not forget to close the stream
```

You forgot to actually write the bytes to the output stream. So, the file is 0 length and naturally doesn't contain any EXIF information.

Also be careful as you are calling `decodeByteArray` and then saving it out again, this will also lose the EXIF information! You need to parse the EXIF from the original image bytes.

Comment: Can you help me out with actual code? I havent done this before.

Comment: Sadly still the same result.

Comment: The part about watching out when calling `decodeByteArray` saved me!

I was trying to get the width and height of the image by doing an unrelated operation utilizing BitmapFactory.Options, setting options.inJustDecodeBounds = true, then running BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options)

But I believe the call to decodeStream was causing the orientation data in the EXIF information to be set to undefined (i.e. be overwritten!)