# Gallery images taken on Samsung androids always in landscape even if taken in portrait

Tags: android, orientation, exif, samsung-mobile, android-gallery

Picking images from gallery with the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

Getting result with the following code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_FILE_RESULT_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            // Get the Uri of the selected file
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            //Using Picasso to load uri to imageView
            //Image is in landscape even if it was taken in portrait

        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine for HTC and Nexus phones, but just for Samsung devices (Galaxy 5 and Galaxy 5 mini) the orientation is wrong if the photo was taken in portrait. When looking at the ExifInterface the orientation is undefined..

```
File imageFile = new File(uri.getPath());
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
//orientation is always 0 for samsung devices = ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED
```

How can I present the images correctly alternative determine the correct orientation so that I can rotate the image?

Comment: send me 2 sample images (1 in each orientation) and I'll tell you if I find any info defining the orientation (bitbank@pobox.com).

Comment: I've sent an email containing the images now, thanks for taking your time! @BitBank

Comment: The images do contain EXIF orientation information. The first is "90 degrees left" and the second is "180 degrees".

Comment: I haven't tried the Android `ExifInterface` class before, but if you find it insufficient, you might find the [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) library useful. For quick testing, Phil Harvey's excellent [Exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) is, well, excellent.

Comment: Thanks for the help @BitBank, I was able to find the orientation, see my answer

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get the orientation with the following code:

```
public static int getExifOrientation(Context context, Uri uri) {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
        id = id.split(":")[1];
        cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                CONTENT_ORIENTATION, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
        if (cursor == null || !cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return 0;
        }
        return cursor.getInt(0);
    } catch (RuntimeException ignored) {
        // If the orientation column doesn't exist, assume no rotation.
        return 0;
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/17/android-re-size-image-without-loosing-exif-information/

Comment: What is CONTENT_ORIENTATION here?