# Display horizontal and vertical images in imageview

Tags: android

I am getting pictures from the sdcard in my app. I am using imageview to display image. However since I dont know if the image will be horizontal or vertical, how can I show horizontal or vertical image in imageview appropriately.Thanks

```
 File img_file = new File(picture_path);
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img_file.getAbsolutePath());
        iv2.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

imageview xml

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_image2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately kind of a complicated thing to do. You can read the Xif data and determine its orientation, see [How to determine orientation of picture without ExifInterface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309863/how-to-determine-orientation-of-picture-without-exifinterface) and [Android get Orientation of a camera Bitmap? And rotate back -90 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286714/android-get-orientation-of-a-camera-bitmap-and-rotate-back-90-degrees) for ideas. Then you can rotate it manually.

Comment: I am trying to understand here, the images are being displayed horizontal or vertical. They don't need to be rotated. My problem is if I hard code the width and height in imageview, the portrait images looked weird in height?kind of look shrunk in. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah... Don't hardcode the width and height. use wrap_content for both. That will get the scale correct. If you want to make a hardcoded image size then you have to tell it how to scale or crop, here's a list of your options: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html